# How to represent scientific notation in C

Tags: c, opencl, scientific-computing, scientific-notation

How do I represent extremely large or small numbers in C with a certain amount of significant figures. For example, if I want to do calculations on 1.54334E-34, how could I do this. Also, is this applicable to OpenCL code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know any OpenCL but 32-bit C floats will hold values in the range of [+/- 3.4e +/- 38 (~7 digits)](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/), and doubles much more. If you want arbitrary precision arithmetic/math you may want to look into [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/).

Answer (score 32):

```
float var = 1.54334E-34;
double var2 = 1.54334E-34;

printf("\n normal:%f\n sci:%e \n or \n sci:%E   \n",var,var,var);
printf("\n normal:%f\n sci:%e \n or \n sci:%E   \n",var2,var2* 1.0E3 ,var2 * 1.0e3);
```